# Ubuntu Server - Download with 500 Byte/s

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu Server 10.04 and should have a connection of 100 MB/s.
The following programs are running:
Apache (with mod_dav_svn)
ProFTPD
MySQL

Apache and ProFTPD are very slow, i have to download with 500 Byte / s.
Any ideas, what I can do to optimize it?

Kind regards

Stefan

Comment: RAM: 2GB + 4GB dynamic RAM. CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 860 @ 2.80GHz, 1 cores. Server is not busy.

Comment: So where is this between - your server and your home? Have you tried it elsewhere? There's really not a great deal of info here and I'm not sure how much we'll be able to help. Surely you ought to speak to your provider about issues with.... your provider? They should know how their network works after all.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess at a upload cap from your ISP (as Ben is suggesting). If this is an external connection, try locally to isolate the bottleneck.